# How to iterate over all nodes in a graph?

Tags: java, graph, directed-graph

I have a directed graph and want to iterate over all the nodes in the graph.

So what is the way in which I can iterate over all the graphs?

Comment: Describe your data structure in more detail.

Comment: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42directed/Digraph.java.html the data structure i am using

Comment: What do you mean by "maintains all the edges in form of a boolean"?

Comment: Where do you store the different nodes (or the information that is assosciated with them?)

Comment: it can be done with a simple symbol table, which I will implement as I need the abstraction. As of now they are just the nodes and edges

Comment: Where in this code are the nodes? If those are identified by their index in the adj-array why don't you simply iterate over this array?

Comment: That class does not explicitly store vertices, but it assumes you have V vertices identified by an integer from 0 to V-1. So there's that. If you mean graph traversal, you need to implement DFS or BFS using the adjacency list.

Comment: or do you want to follow the edges?

Answer (score 2):

In the toString() method, there is an example of iterating over all the nodes:

```
for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) {
    s.append(String.format("%d: ", v));
    for (int w : adj[v]) {
        s.append(String.format("%d ", w));
    }
    s.append(NEWLINE);
}
```

Notice that nodes are simple ints; there are graph.V() nodes, and they are numbered 0 to graph.V() - 1.
That means you can iterate through them with a simple for loop, as above.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you are using stores the graph as an adjacency list in the memory. So just take a single node as source/start node and run any standard graph traversal algorithm (e.g. BFS or DFS) from there to iterate over all the nodes.

Comment: If you only want to iterate over all nodes, this is not needed (also isolated nodes would not be iterated over then)

Comment: This assumes that the graph is strongly connected or that OP only cares about nodes in a tree rooted at the start node.

The example graph in the linked file is not connected, so I assume that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes traversal algorithm is not needed just to iterate over the graph but a DFS will sure traverse every node whether its connected or not. You just have to run it from every node. Like first check whether a node is already visited or not. If not visited run a DFS from there.